_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin@1615499305' has not been initialized
I'm working on a Todos App where i'm using alaram_manager_plus plugin to schedule alarms and fire a notification accordingly , i have set up the code and everything works fine until calling AlarmManager call "fireAlarmManager" , when callback is executed , it is supposed to fire a notification with those params but for some reason it keeps throwing an error ( added below ) , i would like to get some help guys and thank you in advance.

This is error ( Actually I'm initializing it )

_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin@1615499305' has not been initialized



NotificatonHelper Class

class NotificationHelper {

 static late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
 static void initializePlatformSpecifics() async {
   _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
   var initializationSettingsAndroid = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
   var initializationSettingsIOS = const DarwinInitializationSettings(
     requestAlertPermission: true,
     requestBadgePermission: true,
     requestSoundPermission: false,
   );
   var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
     android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
     iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
   );
   await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
 }
 static void showNotification(String param1, String param2) async {
   var androidChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
     'id',
     'Todos',
     importance: Importance.max,
     priority: Priority.high,
     playSound: true,
     timeoutAfter: 5000,
     styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
   );
   var iosChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails();
   var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
     android: androidChannelSpecifics,
     iOS: iosChannelSpecifics,
   );
   await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
     100,
     param1,
     param2,
     platformChannelSpecifics,
     payload: 'New Payload',
   );
 }

}



Code to fire AlarmManager

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
 static void fireAlarmManager(int id, Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
     NotificationHelper.showNotification(params["param1"], params["param2"]);
 }
 Future createAlarm() async {
   await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(
     combineDateTime(dateStamp, timeStamp),
     DateTime.now().minute,
     fireAlarmManager,
     exact: true,
     allowWhileIdle: true,
     wakeup: true,
     rescheduleOnReboot: true,
     params: {
       'param1': "Task is ready!",
       'param2': _taskController.text.toString(),
     },
   );
 }



Initialization


class _TasksDetailsState extends State<TasksDetails> {
 late TodosController _todosController;
 var pickedDate = "";
 var pickedTime = "";
 var pickedColor = "";
 late DateTime dateStamp;
 late TimeOfDay timeStamp;
 var fullDate = 0;
 var selectedColorIndex = 0;
 final List<String> _colors = ["#154a54", "#ff8f38", "#111827", "#ff4500", "#743747", "#467966"];

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _todosController = Get.find();
   NotificationHelper.initializePlatformSpecifics();
 }



Do you ever call initializePlatformSpecifics()? The error seems to imply that a showNotification was called before the initializePlatformSpecifics() happened

Yes , I'm calling in OnInit() , I will update that piece of code

I have added that here on stack , please check it once again , i think because of isolates , i'm not really sure what is exactly going on

Well this init only happen when the TaskDetails screen is loaded. If this alarm is triggered before you visit the TaskDetails screen you'll get that error

Try to call "NotificationHelper.initializePlatformSpecifics();" in your main() before runApp()

Try adding this line in your main method
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()

It ensures the asynchronous call is made before app starts.
I would recommend you to initialize the FlutterLocalNotificationPlugin as singleton using get_it. Then, you can just call it anywhere in your project.

Thank you for your reply , I already have WidgetFlutterBinding added , and i created a singleton now using Getx .. GetPut and use that singleton but still showing the same error ...

can you show me the snippet of your code

Which snippet , i posted all the related code
